# Is there any meaning behind the writing on the wall?

Tags: fire-emblem-echoes-shadows-valentia

While exploring one of the dungeons (I believe it was the Sylvan Shrine), I found this writing on the wall:

[image: writing]

Upon closer inspection, I was informed that it was "not important":

[image: unimportant]

However, I find this hard to believe since the designers bothered to include it here. Is there a special meaning behind this writing on the wall?

Comment: It *doesn't seem important* to me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The writing on the wall is part of a sub-quest called The Prisoner's Whereabouts by the Merchant's Wife in Forest Village. You can look at the details here: https://serenesforest.net/fire-emblem-echoes-shadows-valentia/miscellaneous/sub-quests/

Comment: Huh, seems right. Glad there actually was a reason behind it!